# combination of .items() loop with if

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

How can i combine a loop through a dict with `.items()` and an if condition? It works in an list comprehension and I know I can just loop through the keys and get the item with `test_dict[key]`, but is it possible while using the `.items()` loop?

```
test_dict = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}
skip = ['b']

[print(key,item) for key,item in test_dict.items() if key not in skip] #works

# for key,item in test_dict.items() if key not in skip:
#     print(key,item)
```

Comment: Are you asking how to use a `for` loop and `if` statement on the same line without using a comprehension?

Comment: yes. like the part i commented out in the bottom, but that throws an error

Comment: The reason you have that syntax in the comprehension is to allow you to use what translates to: line 1: `for key,item in test_dict.items():` line 2: `if key not in skip:` in a comprehension. In a normal `for` loop there is no syntax for including the `if` statement on the same line.

Comment: Here's the grammar for a python `for` loop. https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html The part labeled `for_stmt`. You'll notice the part labeled `for_if_clauses` only relates to generator expressions and comprehensions.

Comment: Thanks! Not the answer I was hoping for, but sure the answer for this question

Comment: @Axe319 could you please post it as an answer, so I can close the question?

Comment: I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inline `if` statements exist in `list` comprehensions to allow expressing syntax such as:

```
for key,item in test_dict.items():
    if key not in skip:
       # do stuff
```

within them.

According to the python grammar, there is no way to express an `if` statement on the same line as the standard `for` loop itself.
From https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html

```
for_stmt:
    | 'for' star_targets 'in' ~ star_expressions ':' [TYPE_COMMENT] block [else_block] 
    | ASYNC 'for' star_targets 'in' ~ star_expressions ':' [TYPE_COMMENT] block [else_block]
```

where `star_expressions` refers to multiple `expressions`.
Although an `expression` can have

```
disjunction 'if' disjunction 'else' expression
```

This refers to the actual `dict.items()` and is evaluated only at loop entrance.
Such as:

```
for item in test_dict.values() if True else [1, 2, 3]:
```

You can also see that `for_if_clauses` only relate to comprehensions and generator expressions as they only appear in these definitions.

```
listcomp:
    | '[' named_expression ~ for_if_clauses ']' 
genexp:
    | '(' named_expression ~ for_if_clauses ')' 
setcomp:
    | '{' named_expression ~ for_if_clauses '}' 
dictcomp:
    | '{' kvpair for_if_clauses '}'
```